# Ionic ion-reorder-button breaks design

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code in a modal view

```
<ion-list show-reorder="true" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
  <ion-item  ng-repeat="widget in allWidgets"  class="widgetList" style="vertical-align: middle">

    <div class="widgetListContainer item item-icon-right">
      <div class="widgetListPictureContainer">
        <img src="{{widget.icon}}" class="widgetListPicture"/>
      </div>
      <div class="widgetListText">
        {{widget.title}}
      </div>
    </div>

  <ion-reorder-button></ion-reorder-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And the CSS

```
.widgetListContainer{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.widgetListPictureContainer{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25%;

}

.widgetListPicture{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 20px;
}

.widgetListText{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.widgetIconContainer {
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

The list and the items are supposed to be in a dark color. However, the row is displayed white.
The strange thing is, if I remove the , the list is displayed correctly. 
It seems like the  is breaking the design and somehow coloring everything in white, although set differently in the CSS.

Anything I could do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It looks like that the ionic Framework wraps the content of the ion-item in another div when adding reorder button to ensure that the content of the ion-item and the button have enough space.
So the design of this "wrap-div" has to be overwritten

```
.item-content {
  background-color: #212121 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great!
For me I used the code below for my list could vary the colors .
It's working!!

```
.item-content { 
    background-color:inherit !important; 
}
```